# Framerate issues on Samsung S8

Tags: android, arcore

I have been using ARCore to develop some applications, and I've noticed the tracking framerate varies by device within the same capability range.

For example, on a Samsung S8, the video framerate from ARCore is pegged at 30fps. The same app on a Pixel 2 runs at 60 fps.

Is there a way to increase the framerate on Samsung phones or a justification for the difference between devices?